# How to sort according to key in an Ordered Collection in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I am trying to sort an `OrderedCollection` via its keys, but this method returns just the keys. I want to get both keys and values, but sorted based on keys.

```
aAssociation:= Association new.
aAssociation key:6 value:7.
aOrderedCollection:= OrderedCollection new.
aOrderedCollection addFirst: aAssociation.
aAssociation1:= Association new.
aAssociation1 key:5 value:9.
aOrderedCollection addLast: aAssociation1.
aAssociation2:= Association new.
aAssociation2 key:8 value:4.
aOrderedCollection addLast: aAssociation2.
aSortedCollection:= (aOrderedCollection sort: #key ascending) collect:#key.
```

Comment: Try `z asSortedCollection: [:a :b | a key < b key]`. This will answer with a `SortedCollection`. Most dialects have also some `sort` messages that accept the block and sort the collection in place (or answer with a copy of it). Browse the `OrderedCollection` class and look for the appropriate one.

Comment: Yes this worked as well as if I just type z asSortedCollection, that also return the sorted list. Thanks.

Comment: A) Please don't edit your question to add new questions not related to the title - use a separate question for that. B) Which Smalltalk flavour are you actually doing this in? Please don't just add a bunch of Smalltalk-related tags to the question. C) Please browse the classes you're calling `new` on. On the class side, you'll find ways to create instances of these directly while setting initial values at the same time. D) Smalltalk uses (or should use) meaningful names for things; `y`, `y1`, etc. are not good names. Happy to remove my downvote when at least some of these are addressed.

Comment: Ok from next time I will be careful. I am using virtualworks. I will edit the variable names.

Comment: Thanks @Mia, downvote removed. I've also taken the liberty of removing the extra tags that don't apply; I'm assuming by "virtualworks" you mean "VisualWorks" Smalltalk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re calling #collect: at the end, which is where you extract the keys. Don’t do that and you’re done.

Also don’t call #sort:, it would modify the collection you send it to. Use #sorted:, it will return a sorted copy. It will also work on all kinds of collections.